# Por que no se pueden eliminar metodos en python?

Tags: python

-La pregunta seria la siguiente : *por que no se pueden eliminar los metodos a traves del uso de la palabra clave `del`*

-En el caso de decorarlos con un deletter, no se trataria de lo mismo, ya que en tales casos se estarian eliminando los objetos a los cuales es relativo el metodo decorado con `@property`, no el metodo en si

-Recordemos que al fin y al cabo, las funciones son (al igual que todo en python) objetos, punteros que apuntan a variables, en este caso, dichas variables serian el bloque de codigo que carga en RAM, por ejemplo ...

```
  def saludo():
      print('Hola como estamos por aca? ')
```

-En este caso `saludo` en si mismo, sin el uso del dunder `__call__` (es decir sin llamar a los parentesis), es un puntero que apunta a `saludo()`, es por lo mismo que con estos si podemos emplear la palabra clave `del` sin que hayan errores, ya que (si no me equivoco, es lo que mi intuicion me indica, si tiene razones para decir que me equivoco en algo, por favor digalo), lo que hace `del` es basicamente hacer que `saludo` (como puntero) apunte a `None`. Y ahi radica la pregunta, *por que si las funciones y los metodos son basicamente lo mismo, no pueden eliminarse con la misma facilidad.*

-Destacar que eliminar un metodo dado que esta decorado con un `deletter`, no entra en mi percepcion de eliminacion, ya que, como mencione al principio, en tales casos se eliminarian los atributos a los que es relativo ese metodo, no al metodo en si.

Comment: ¿Puedes mencionar una aplicación de tal funcionalidad?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Claro que se pueden eliminar métodos en python. Un método no es más que un atributo y como indicas en la pregunta es una especie de "apuntador" al código de la función.

Una función es en el fondo un objeto (de un tipo especial "llamable") y el nombre de la función no es más que un símbolo que apunta a la función. Cuando borras ese símbolo con `del simbolo`, simplemente "rompes" la conexión que había entre ese símbolo y el objeto al que apuntaba. El objeto queda indefinido (que no es lo mismo que con valor `None`), y un intento de acceder a ese símbolo dará error:

```
>>> def f():
...   pass
...
>>> f
<function f at 0x102310af0>
>>> del f
>>> f
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'f' is not defined
```

El símbolo `f` ha dejado de existir, pero el objeto (función) al que apuntaba quizás no. En particular, si tienes otro símbolo apuntando al mismo objeto, el objeto seguirá existiendo:

```
>>> def f():
...   return "Existo"
...
>>> f()
'Existo'
>>> g = f
>>> g()
'Existo'
>>> del f
>>> g()
'Existo'
```

Como ves, `del f` no elimina la función en sí, sino sólo al símbolo `f` que apuntaba a la función. La función aún existe y puede ser llamada a través del símbolo `g`. Sólo cuando todos los símbolos que apuntaban a ese objeto desaparecen, el objeto es finalmente eliminado de memoria por el recolector de basura.

### ¿Y los métodos?

Con los métodos ocurre lo mismo, sólo que hay un matiz. Un método no es más que un atributo que "apunta" a una función, pero ese atributo puede existir como parte del objeto o como parte de la clase. Veamos primero un ejemplo con atributos que no son métodos, sino por ejemplo enteros:

```
>>> class A:
...   x = 1
...
>>> a = A()
>>> a.y = 2
```

La clase `A` tiene un atributo llamado `x`. El objeto `a` (que es una instancia de la clase `A`) tiene otro atributo llamado `y`. Aunque el usuario puede tratar de acceder a `a.x`, en realidad `x` no existe como parte de `a`, sino como parte de la clase (y el objeto lo "hereda").

Esto implica que podremos borrar `a.y` pero no `a.x` porque `a` en realidad no tiene el atributo x:

```
>>> a.x
1
>>> a.y
2
>>> del a.x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: x
>>> del a.y
```

En cambio no hay ningún problema en borrarlo de la clase (que es donde en realidad existe):

```
>>> del A.x
>>>
```

Naturalmente una vez lo hemos borrado de la clase, cualquier instancia posterior no podrá heredarlo:

```
>>> b = A()
>>> b.x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Con los métodos pasa **exactamente lo mismo**. Sólo que en casi todos los casos los métodos pertenecen a la clase, y no al objeto. Por tanto si quieres borrarlos deberás hacerlo a través de la clase:

```
>>> class A:
...   def foo(self):
...     return "Existo"
...
>>> a = A()
>>> a.foo()
'Existo'
>>> del a.foo    # No podemos porque foo no existe en a, sino en A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: foo
>>> del A.foo    # Esto en cambio no da problemas
>>> a.foo()      # Ahora fallará el intento de usarlo desde una instancia
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

Comment: buena la respuesta, sin embargo me quedaron algunas dudas, algo extensas como para ponerlas en un comentario, voy a formular otra pregunta, espero  tu respuesta : - |