# ¿Qué son las clases realmente (Python)?

Tags: python, poo

-Hasta hace poco creía que las clases eran 'moldes' que se empleaban para la creación de objetos; sin embargo, esta pregunta ([Por que no se pueden eliminar metodos en python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/452648/por-que-no-se-pueden-eliminar-metodos-en-python/452692#452692)) me hizo cuestionarme algunas cosas. Lo que se dice en la respuesta más votada es que, en resumen, sí se pueden eliminar los métodos ya que, al igual que cualquier otra cosa, los métodos (sin paréntesis) son básicamente apuntadores que guardan la referencia ('apuntan') al código del método que carga en RAM. En otras palabras: son atributos de toda la vida sólo que, en este caso, apuntan a codigo y no a datos normales, por ende al emplear la palabra reservada `del` lo que hacemos es eliminar las referencias que guarda ese puntero, lo que se traduce en 'cortar' el 'enlace' que tiene ese puntero con la(s) variable(s) a la(s) que apunta (por lo que entiendo tambien pueden guardar varias referencias, sería lo mismo que pasaría con las listas por ejemplo, al menos es así como funciona en `C` y supongo que será lo mismo que pasa en python (si no es así, coméntenlo por favor) por ende ya no podemos acceder a nada a traves de él,  ya que ya no apunta a ningún sitio...

- Hasta aquí todo bien, la pregunta se empieza a presentar cuando se menciona que los objetos *heredan* de las clases a partir de las cuales son instanciados, es por lo mismo que no se puede eliminar un metodo a traves de un objeto, ya que ese método no es suyo sino de su *clase*, esto tiene mucho sentido, ya que (como se puede ver en la publicación) partiendo de esa premisa todo funciona.

-Con lo cual, la pregunta sería la siguiente : ¿Las clases son realmente '*moldes*'? ¿Qué es lo que pasa realmente cuando creamos e instanciamos un objeto a partir de una clase? (eliminando todas las capas de abtracción, que es lo que pasa realmente en RAM)

**ARGUMENTO**

-Tenía entendido lo siguiente ...

```
class persona:
    def __init__(self, nombre, apellido, edad, sexo) -> None:
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.apellido = apellido
        self.edad = edad
        self.sexo = sexo

persona_nueva = persona('Jhon','Doe', 33, 'h')
```

-En este caso, `persona_nueva` sería entonces un puntero que almacenaría la referencia a un objeto (en este caso podemos entender a objeto como un conjunto de punteros), por lo tanto, ejecutar ...

```
print(persona_nueva.nombre)
```

-Sería como decirle a `persona_nueva` (prescindiendo un poco de la participación de _ _ str _ _): 'pasale al `print` el valor del lugar a donde apunta ese puntero al que estas apuntando, ese tal `nombre`' (ésta sería mas o menos la estructura que se forma en mi cabecita)

```
                ____-nombre -> 'Jhon'
               /    -apellido -> 'Doe'
 persona_nueva      -edad -> 33
                    -sexo -> 'h'
```

ya `persona_nueva`  accedió a `nombre` ...

```
persona_nueva.nombre -> print
```

Es por lo mismo que `del persona_nueva.nombre` funciona (al menos en mi máquina), ya que sería equivalente a ...

```
                ____-nombre -> 'Jhon'
               \    -apellido -> 'Doe'
 persona_nueva      -edad -> 33
                    -sexo -> 'h'
```

y por lo tanto ...

```
                    -apellido -> 'Doe'
 persona_nueva      -edad -> 33
                    -sexo -> 'h'
```

-Pues bien, el caso es que si se tratase de un método (es decir si nombre por ejemplo fuere un método) y que por lo tanto ...

```
                    -nombre -> nombre()
                    -apellido -> 'Doe'
 persona_nueva      -edad -> 33
                    -sexo -> 'h'
```

En este caso, ya no se podria ejecutar `del persona_nueva.nombre`... Esto es básicamente lo que pregunte en (Por que no se pueden eliminar metodos en python?), en respuesta se me dijo que es por que tecnicamente, los atributos no son de `persona_nueva` (objeto) sino de su clase `persona`, pero si este es el caso, por que puedo eliminarle atributos (utilizar `del`) a `persona_nueva` y no métodos, teniendo estos el mismo comportamiento. Muy probablemente sea por que no conozco bien que es una clase, de ahi la pregunta ...

Comment: La respuesta es bastante más compleja que pensar en métodos y atributos. Todo el funcionamiento de la _herencia_, así como la búsqueda de atributos en una jerarquía de clases, se realiza por el mecanismo conocido por **protocolo descriptor**. Esa diferencia que observas entre atributo y método no es otra cosa que la diferencia entre _descriptor de datos_ y _descriptor de no-datos_. Hace tiempo hice unos [artículos sobre descriptores](https://blog.ch3m4.org/tag/descriptor/) que pueden darte alguna idea.

Comment: En otras palabras, invocar a `juan.decir('hola')` es el equivalente a invocar a `Persona.decir(juan, 'hola')`, que no se si pueda hacerse de esa forma, pero es en lo que se traduce la llamada.

Comment: @jachguate sobre tu ultimo comentario, confirmo que si se puede hacer de esta forma. Por ejemplo `str.strip("  hola mundo  ")` devuelve `"hola mundo"`.

Comment: @jachguate entendido, ciertamente no seria muy eficiente que cargaran 1000 metodos en memoria (en caso de haber 1000 personas claro) siendo el comportamiendo de todos exactamente el mismo, teniendo tambien en cuenta que las clases son, al igual que todo en python, punteros . Buena respuesta, establecelo como una respuesta formal y te doy el check

Comment: @PySanti, terminé escribiendo la respuesta, pues ya en el tercer comentario comencé a darme cuenta que comentarios no era el mejor lugar para tanto. Borraré, por tanto, mis comentarios originales. Debo aclarar que no soy experto ni mucho menos en python, así que si más adelante aparece una respuesta más propia, no dudes en cambiar de parecer sobre lo que yo he dicho. Un saludo.

Comment: Creo ques una mala idea intentar darle sentido a tu código de Python en térimo de apuntadores y abstracciones de bajo nivel. Quedate con las abstracciones que te proporciona python, por ejemplo, todo en python es un objecto(métodos, funciones, etc) esto hace más fácil acceptar hechos como que una función puede tener argumentos que son agregados en tiempo de ejecución y no te encapsula en la fantasia de que una función es un apuntador solamente. Posiblemente con el tiempo puedas ver y entender las abstracciones de más bajo nivel que forman a python pero mientras tanto creo que no es necesario.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Buff! Pregunta interesante, respuesta compleja. Aunque podría responderse en diferentes niveles (es lo bueno de python, puedes quedarte en un nivel durante años sin necesitar nada del nivel inferior).

### Nivel más alto. Las clases son plantillas

Una clase es una plantilla que permite crear objetos. Esta explicación es errónea en el sentido de que los objetos creados no son meras "copias" de la clase, sino que contienen más bien referencias a la clase, para evitar por ejemplo duplicar el código de los métodos, como menciona @jachguate en su respuesta. No obstante puedes trabajar con ese modelo mental sin encontrar fisuras durante bastante tiempo.

No obstante esa explicación no aclara por qué hay que poner un parámetro `self` en cada uno de los métodos de la clase. O la diferencia entre un atributo de clase y un atributo de objeto. O entre un staticmethod y un método normal.

Así que profundicemos un poco más.

### Nivel medio. Las clases son objetos

Todo en python son objetos. Una función es un objeto. Una clase también es un objeto, pero que tiene la capacidad de, al ser invocadas, crear objetos nuevos. Son de hecho la única forma de crear objetos definidos por el usuario.

Entonces quizás haya que aclarar antes **¿qué es un objeto?**.

Muy en el fondo podríamos decir que un objeto es un diccionario. De hecho, está implementado como tal, pero ofrece otras formas de interactuar con él. Dentro de todo objeto hay un atributo con nombre predefinido llamado `__dict__` y ese es el diccionario que contiene todos los atributos del objeto y sus valores.

Por ejemplo, como antes se ha dicho, una función es un objeto. Cuando escribes:

```
def f():
  "Ejemplo"
  return 0
```

Se crea un objeto de tipo `function`, y una referencia `f` que apunta a ese objeto `function`. La referencia no es más que un nombre, y puedes pensar en ella como un apuntador. La función en sí no es `f`, sino el objeto `function` al que `f` apunta. Al ser un objeto, tiene su `__dict__` que podemos consultar:

```
>>> f.__dict__
{}
```

Está vacío por defecto porque las funciones, aunque son objetos, por defecto no tienen atributos. Nada nos impediría crearlos (aunque no es práctica común, pero a veces pueden usarse para almacenar en ellos datos que se conserven entre diferentes invocaciones a la función):

```
>>> f.test = 1
>>> f.__dict__
{'test': 1}
```

Pero no solo hay atributos en los objetos. Contienen de hecho más cosas, como una documentación (almacenada en su `.__doc__`), o una referencia a su tipo (la clase de la cual son instancia), almacenada en su `.__class__`. En este ejemplo:

```
>>> f.__doc__
'Ejemplo'
>>> f.__class__
<class 'function'>
```

Vemos así que `f` es en realidad una instancia de `<class 'function'>`, pero esa clase es a su vez un objeto, por lo que también tendrá sus `.__doc__`, `.__dict__` y hasta `.__class__`:

```
>>> f.__class__.__doc__
'Create a function object.\n\n  code\n    a code object\n  globals\n    the globals dictionary\n  name\n    a string that overrides the name from the code object\n  argdefs\n    a tuple that specifies the default argument values\n  closure\n    a tuple that supplies the bindings for free variables'
>>> f.__class__.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__repr__': <slot wrapper '__repr__' of 'function' objects>, '__call__': <slot wrapper '__call__' of 'function' objects>, '__get__': <slot wrapper '__get__' of 'function' objects>, '__new__': <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x10f369880>, '__closure__': <member '__closure__' of 'function' objects>, '__doc__': <member '__doc__' of 'function' objects>, '__globals__': <member '__globals__' of 'function' objects>, '__module__': <member '__module__' of 'function' objects>, '__code__': <attribute '__code__' of 'function' objects>, '__defaults__': <attribute '__defaults__' of 'function' objects>, '__kwdefaults__': <attribute '__kwdefaults__' of 'function' objects>, '__annotations__': <attribute '__annotations__' of 'function' objects>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'function' objects>, '__name__': <attribute '__name__' of 'function' objects>, '__qualname__': <attribute '__qualname__' of 'function' objects>})
>>> f.__class__.__class__
<class 'type'>
```

Esto ya nos permite diferenciar un poco mejor entre una clase y una instancia de la clase. Ambos son objetos, pero contienen diferente información.

Cuando escribes una clase propia, como por ejemplo:

```
class C:
  x = 1
  def __init__(self, n=0):
     self.n = n
  def metodo(self):
     return self.n
```

Creamos un objeto de tipo `class`, que tiene su propio `__dict__`, dentro del cual hay entre otras cosas las claves `"x"` , `"__init__"` y `"metodo"`. La primera contiene simplemente un entero (1) y las siguientes contienen un objeto-función (llamados `C.__init__` y `C.metodo`, respectivamente)

Cuando instancias esa clase para crear un objeto, por ejemplo con

```
o = C(3)
```

se ejecuta su inicializador el cual hace la asignación `self.n=3`. En ese momento `self` es el objeto recién creado, por tanto un objeto nuevo. El atributo `n` formará parte de `o.__dict__`, pero no de `C.__dict__`.

```
>>> o = C(3)
>>> o.__dict__
{'n': 3}
```

Como vemos, en el diccionario de `o` sólo existe la clave `'n'`. Sin embargo eso no nos impide tratar de acceder a `o.x`:

```
>>> o.x
1
```

Ocurre que python buscará primero un atributo llamado `"x"` dentro de `o.__dict__`. Si lo encuentra habrá terminado ahi. Si no lo encuentra, usará `o.__class__` para saber la clase de la que es instancia, y usará entonces `o.__class__.__dict__` para buscar allí `"x"`, donde lo encontrará con valor 1. Es por eso que todas las instancias de esa clase comparten ese atributo, porque no está en cada objeto, sino en la clase.

Por cierto que este comportamiento se aplica sólo para *leer* el atributo. Si en cambio lo asignamos, eso creará siempre una nueva entrada en el `__dict__` del objeto:

```
>>> o.x = 100
>>> o.__dict__
{'n': 3, 'x': 100}
>>> o.__dict__["x"]
100
>>> o.__class__.__dict__["x"]
1
```

Los métodos operan de forma similar (al menos al nivel en que lo estamos explicando ahora, que no es aún el más profundo). Cuando hacemos `o.metodo()`, se busca `"metodo"` en `o.__dict__` y al no encontrarlo se busca en `o.__class__.__dict__` donde se encuentra que es una referencia a una función. En ese momento Python lo transforma en lo que llama un "método de instancia" (pero no altera `o.__dict__`), que es una función especial que recibirá como primer parámetro el objeto concreto a través del cual fue llamado.

Es decir, que `o.metodo()` equivale en el fondo a:

```
>>> o.__class__.__dict__["metodo"](o)
3
>>> o.metodo()
3
```

### Y aún hay más niveles

En realidad, la búsqueda de un atributo en un objeto es algo que se puede redefinir. Lo que expliqué antes es cómo se hace *por defecto*, pero si la clase `C` definiera un método llamado `__getattribute__()`, entonces python lo usaría para buscar el atributo dado en `o`. De modo que `o.foo` se traduciría en `C.__getattribute__(o, "foo")`, y esa función podría decidir retornar cualquier cosa, saltándose por tanto el papel de `o.__dict__` y  de  `C.__dict__`.

Esto a su vez puede ser más complejo al tener en cuenta la herencia (y la posibilidad de herencia múltiple), que causaría llamadas recursivas "hacia arriba" en el árbol de herencia, según un orden bien definido (MRO). Y habría que hablar del [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)

Y no he querido entrar en cómo se crea el objeto en sí, que es algo de lo que normalmente se ocupa python, pero sobre lo que tenemos control también si queremos, mediante la implementación del método especial `__new__()` en la clase. Ese método es el que debe retornar el objeto recién creado sobre el que luego se aplicará `__init__()`.

Todos los detalles están por supuesto en [la documentación del modelo de datos](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)

Answer (score 2):

Dejando del lado la parte conceptual de la clase como *un molde*, si lo ves desde otro punto de vista, en tiempo de ejecución cada instancia de `Persona` tiene que tener todos sus atributos (`nombre`, `apellido`, etc). Si tienes 1000 personas (y obviando otras optimizaciones), habrá en memoria 1000 nombres, 1000 apellidos, etc.

Sin embargo un método, digamos `saludar()`, existirá en memoria una única vez (tanto el código para ejecutarlo, como la referencia a este código).

Dado que solo tienen que estar una vez, estos *atributos* son almacenados en la clase misma, y no en cada instancia, donde no tendría tanto sentido.

Cuando invocas al método sobre una instancia, digamos `juan.saludar()`, lo que pasa tras bambalinas es que `juan` tiene un apuntador a la clase `Persona` (su clase) y esta clase es la que tiene el apuntador al código del método `saludar()`. La llamada se construye pasándole a dicha función, como primer parámetro, el apuntador a la instancia sobre la que va a operar (el auto-parámetro self), en este caso, una referencia a `juan`.

En otras palabras, invocar a `juan.decir('hola')` es el equivalente a invocar a `Persona.decir(juan, 'hola')`, que no se si pueda hacerse de esa forma, pero es en lo que se *traduce* la llamada.

El modelo subyacente sobre el que opera python es bastante diferente de c++ y otros lenguajes compilados... en donde es en tiempo de compilación que se resuelven muchas de estas referencias y se calculan las direcciones en memoria de los atributos, lo que hace menos flexible al modelo.

En python, ya que todo se resuelve en tiempo de corrida, se puede manipular más libremente la estructura de una clase o de sus instancias, aún después de tener copias en memoria, de una forma que no podría hacerse en c++ o en Pascal, por mencionar algunos lenguajes.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando un poco la respuesta dada, lo que pasa cuando se crea una clase y esta es instanciada, se crea un objeto vacio, el cual muchas veces es llenado con un *constructor* `__init__`. Pongamos un ejemplo:

```py
class persona():
    pass
    #puedes crear métodos pero igual se creará un objeto vacío al instanciarlo

persona_nueva = persona() #crea un objeto vacío
```

En tu caso defines un constructor `__init__` esto hace que la clase inmediatamente llame a este método en el cual se asigna los atributos, estos son creados al momento de instanciar la clase (llamar a un objeto `__call__`)
Lo que pasará aquí será, efectivamente, que habrá en memoria la misma cantidad de instancias y atributos que tengas (#a*#i) tal y como se explicó en la otra respuesta.

En cambio los métodos son funciones, las cuales se ejecutan al momento de llamar a la función y por ende crean y asignan las variables al momento de ser llamadas, una funcion al ser llamada desde una instancia genera un puntero a tal clase, esto ya se explico por lo que lo dejare hasta aquí.

Cuando se crea una clase esta se ejecuta en un nuevo marco de ejecución utilizando nombres *locales* recién creados, esto tiene que ver con el *scope* de una clase, pero que pasa cuando esta finaliza?, cuando ya se ha creado un nuevo objeto su marco de ejecución se descarta, sin embargo esta guarda el espacio de nombres locales.

**Herencia**
La herencia es algo fundamental en la programación orientada a objetos, cuando el objeto clase se construye, se tiene en cuenta a la clase base, esto ayuda a resolver referencias de atributos y métodos solicitados que no se encuentran, a lo que python procede a buscar en la clase base, **Todas** las clases que crees heredan por defecto a una clase base `object` esta clase tiene todos los métodos que son comunes a todas las instancias, esta clase no tiene un metodo `__dict__` lo que no hace posible asignar atributos a la instancia de esta clase.

**¿Qué es el scope?**
Antes hablamos sobre el scope de una clase. El scope es la visibilidad de un nombre en un bloque, algo similar al `var, let` de *javascript* el primero indica que la varible sera accedida desde cualquier parte y el segundo que solo funcione en un bloque especifico. Cuando un nombre no se encuentra se lanza una excepción `NameError`. Hay que recordar que python vincula las variables, [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/306662/por-qu%c3%a9-el-operador-is-no-funciona-para-comparar-valores/306705#306705) hay un pequeño ejemplo, no es del mismo tema pero sirve para explicarlo.